# jQuery - how to write a if promt checking for childNode.length, nextSibling and childNode.nodeType

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I need some good examples of how to write a if-statement checking all my `div's` for specified number of childNodes.lenght and childNode.nodeType.

And in addition to be 100 percent sure i got the right `<div>` and its right node also check for the nextSibling.

I am pretty new to jQuery/javascript so i might struggle in the syntax but here is what i got so far:

`var specifiedChildNodesLength = ...`

`var specifiedChildNodesType = ...`

`if( $('div').childNodes.length == specifiedChildNodesLength && 
$('div').childNodes.nodeType == specifiedChildNodesType) { do something }`

Comment: You're mixing native DOM properties with jQuery. Which do you want?

Comment: `$('div')` selects *all* divs in the whole page. Didn't you want to get a particular one?

Comment: Have you tried writing and testing any code yourself? You shouldn't expect stackoverflow to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (($('div').children().length == specifiedChildNodesLength) && ($('div').children().get(0).nodeType == specifiedChildNodesType)) {}
```